# PHP recursion function returns NULL - Carbon PHP library

Tags: php, function, recursion, php-carbon

Im trying to write a recursive function with the help of Carbon PHP DateTime library. But if I run the function the return value is NULL, even when before it I echo it and it is echoed correctly.

The recursive function is searching for a next available weekday, so there is 6 and 0 for Saturday and Sunday. I just testing it for the function for now.

Every help apprecieted.

Thanks.

```
$today = Carbon::now($timezone);

$variable = check_next_day($today);
var_dump($variable); //NULL

function check_next_day($giventdate){

//var_dump ($giventdate->dayOfWeek);
/*echo "<br>Holnapi nap:" . $giventdate->addDay();
echo "<br>Holnapi nap erteke:" . $giventdate->dayOfWeek; */
//echo gettype($giventdate->dayOfWeek);


if ( ($giventdate->dayOfWeek == 1 ) || ( $giventdate->dayOfWeek == 2 ) ){
    //echo ( "<br>IN loop:". $giventdate);
    check_next_day($giventdate->addDay());
} else {
    //echo "ELSE VAN?". $giventdate; // This returns the correct value  2017-02-08 19:44:46
    return $giventdate; // This returns NULL
}
    //print_r (check_next_day($giventdate->addDay()));
    //echo "WTF";

}
```

Comment: in the first branch of your if-statement, you **don't return anything**. that's not very recursive...

Comment: I tried it like this, but in this case NULL is returned too. And there is a wrong value in giventdate, because if $giventdate->dayOfWeek is 1 it runs the if statement not the else.
if ( ($giventdate->dayOfWeek != 1 ) || ( $giventdate->dayOfWeek != 2 ) ){
  echo ( "<br>IN loop:". $giventdate);
  return $giventdate;
  
 } else {
  check_next_day($giventdate->addDay());
 }

Comment: In a recursive method, every possible execution branch must eventually return *something*. Unless PHP defaults and returns null (which would explain the error), I would expect this to throw an error.

Comment: @beamkiller In your code you posted just now, you still aren't returning anything in the else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys... Maybe I am too tired :D

```
function check_next_day($giventdate){

    if ( ($giventdate->dayOfWeek == 1 ) || ( $giventdate->dayOfWeek == 2 ) ){
        check_next_day($giventdate->addDay());
        return $giventdate;
    } else {
        return $giventdate; 
    }
}
```